Change NLOG minlevel from app service?? without causing restart
In short is it possible to change the minlevel for NLog, without causing an app restart on azure, as pushing a code change will restart the app and changing a value in the azure app config will cause a restart. We do not want to restart the app
.Net 4.8 C# API, currently writes its logs to our database using NLog, which is all working.
However, I have now set the log level to pull the value from our web.config. (Which I got working with some help: NLog config file - pull value from WebConfig/App service config)
Using: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer
Which is all working so I have a values in web.config
 <add key="NLog_Record" value="Info" />

then in NLog I say:
<rules>
    <logger name="Log" minlevel="${appsetting:name=NLog_Record:default=None}" writeTo="DatabaseName" />
  </rules>

which going by the above will only log the info messages, and this all works great.
However I have pushed our changes to app service. and tested from there adding NLog_Record to app service configuration, logging info for Dev app service and Error for QA App Service, and this all works great.
However, my questions is when I change the NLog_Record value on the app service config, to say for example 'Error' instead of 'Info' and save, this restarts the app service.
I do not want to restart the app service.
I have been looking for a work around but am struggling, has anyone any ideas? Thanks for any replies.
UPDATE
Just had an idea to pull the value from Keyvault in the app service config settings, which wouldnt cause an app re-set, but the values in the Key vault dont get sync until 24 hours, unless a restart is triggered, which we dont want

How you are setting the KeyVault value in App Settings?

you can call a value in the key vault using app settings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEaCnhvggz0


Just had an idea to pull the value from Keyvault in the app service config settings, which wouldnt cause an app re-set,


Yes, the approach you want to try is correct.

You can store the configuration loglevels/values in KeyVault secrets.

From there you can refer those secret in App Service with KeyVault reference.


@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://kvharshu3may.vault.azure.net/secrets/SampleSecret/)


AFAIK,there will be no delay in retrieving the KeyVault latest or the existing secrets.

Yes, the link which you shared to set Secrets in App Service is correct.


Key vault dont get sync until 24 hours, unless a restart is triggered


Restart - That is the actual behavior of the App Service Configuration settings.



But this happens only when you want to add/update any setting.

Whenever you update/add any Application/Connection String the App service gets restarted on every save.

To get the latest value from the Key Vault without restart, you don`t have to update every time.

You Just need to set the Key Vault reference with SecretName (excluding the Secret URI ID).

The below option is not required in this case.




No need to update the App Setting value everytime to get latest changes.

Refer this SOThread which explains how to retrieve KeyVault Secrets from App Settings Configuration.
Another Alternative Approach:

Instead of storing the configuration in App Service => Environment variables, you can directly retrieve the secrets in your App using  DefaultAzureCredential.

This doesn't require any restart of the App Service.

It gets the latest available secret directly from Key Vault.


